# Retrieving YouTube insights via URLs

Tags: c#, youtube

I'm attempting to retrieve YouTube insights using C#.
I have been able to retrieve video Ids with the code below, 
however, I cannot retrieve the insights.  I'm hoping that 
by using the video ID I can do a Get on the following URL:

https://insight.youtube.com/video-analytics/csvreports?query=VIDEO_ID&type=v&starttime=1330727299&endtime=1331677699&region=world&hl=en_US&userName=USERNAME&password=PASSWORD&token=DEV_TOKEN

Though this URL doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas? A specific C# code example would be invaluable.

```
public class UnixTime
{
   public static string ToUnixTime(DateTime dateTime)
    {
        return (Math.Round((dateTime - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0).ToLocalTime()).TotalSeconds, 0)).ToString() ;
    }
}



public void PrepareAndDownloadFile(string username, string password, string token, 
                                   string channel,  string destination)
{

    YouTubeRequestSettings settings = new YouTubeRequestSettings(channel, token, username, password);
    YouTubeRequest request = new YouTubeRequest(settings);
    string feedUrl = String.Format("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/{0}/uploads?v=2", channel);
    Feed<Video> videoFeed = request.Get<Video>(new Uri(feedUrl));

    foreach (Video video in videoFeed.Entries)
    {
        StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder();

        url.Append("https://insight.youtube.com/video-analytics/csvreports");
        url.Append(String.Format("?query={0}", video.VideoId));
        url.Append("&type=v");
        url.Append(String.Format("&starttime={0}", UnixTime.ToUnixTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(SINCE_OFFSET))));
        url.Append(String.Format("&endtime={0}", UnixTime.ToUnixTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(UNTIL_OFFSET))));
        url.Append("&region=world");
        url.Append("&hl=en_US");
        url.Append(String.Format("&userName={0}", username));
        url.Append(String.Format("&password={0}", password));
        url.Append(string.Format("&token={0}", token));

        // make Http Request here given the new url.

        dynamic rows = GetPath(url.ToString());
        processor.WriteRows(destination, rows);
     }
 }
```

Comment: What, specifically, doesn't work? Does your computer blow up? Did you get an error message?

Comment: I should be able to enter this URL into my browser and retrieve the data:


https : //insight.youtube.com/video-analytics/csvreports?query=VIDEO_ID&type=v&starttime=1330727299&endtime=1331677699&region=world&hl=en_US&userName=USERNAME&password=PASSWORD&token=DEV_TOKEN&alt=json


It should come back as a JSON string.  It doesn't. First question is what is the proper incantation to retrieve data.

Comment: @WillHughes - The error I get from YouTube is 404.

Answer (score 1):

Jeffrey Posnick Post reply

10:53 AM (1 hour ago)

Hello,

I don't have any C# code readily available, but I can tell you what 
you're doing wrong. You should not be manually creating YouTube 
Insight URLs. You can't do it. You seem to be using your YouTube 
authentication token as the value of the "token=" URL parameter, and 
sticking your username and password in the URL for good measure, but 
that's completely the wrong approach. The Insight URL is uniquely 
generated by the API and exposed in an authenticated request for a 
video entry by that entry's owner, in a  element. This is 
explained at

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_insight

Again, you can't manually create the URL. The only time you need to 
modify the automatically generated URL at all is if you want to modify 
the user_starttime or user_endtime parameters, which is also covered 
in the docs.

Cheers, 
-Jeff Posnick, YouTube API Team 
groups.google.com/group/youtube-api-gdata | apiblog.youtube.com | 
@YouTubeDev

Comment: Hmmm...has anyone ever used the .Net API to retrieve insights? I'm providing the e-mail address and password of the YouTube account.  The token is the dev key. 

The Video objects that come back  from the call  

Feed<Video> videoFeed = request.Get<Video>(new Uri(feedUrl));
Do not appear to have any Link collections or lists that can be interrogated.
Is this an omission on the part of the providers of the YouTube .Net interface, or am I doing something 
incorrect? Can you have one of your .NET API developers advise me where to find the Link objects
within the Feed<Video> list? 

Thank you.